# Convert MultiArray to SingleArray without foreach

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array, with a single array inside it. Is there a way push the child array  values into the parent without having to run a foreach?

For example, if I have an array like this:

```
array( [0] => array(
               "key1" => "value1",
               "key2" => "value2",
                "key3" => "value3",
               )
     );
```

and I want to reduce it to this:

```
  array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
    "key3" => "value3",
   );
```

Is there a way of doing this without a foreach?

at the moment I'm doing this:

```
$singleArr = array();
foreach($multiArr as $subArr) {
   $singleArr = $subArr;
}
```

Comment: This was asked again a couple minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821550/transformation-multidimensional-array-into-single-array

Answer (score 1):

What about simple:

```
$singleArr = $multiArr[0];
```

Comment: I'll accept when I can. BTW i think this is a good question for a lot people, although easily solved, I imagine it's quite common